# How to show overlay in layout legend

Tags: legend, overlay

I am displaying three different layers on a map, essentially three separate habitat types. Each have their own colour.  In cases, 2 or 3 of the layers overlap in part (essentially showing where habitat types overlap).  How can I display this overlap in the legend?

Comment: Good question.  I know two ways to do it (and there could be other better ways I just dont know of)  One would be to create new polygons of the overlapping area and symbolize them that way.  The second way would be to export out your legend to inkscape/illustrator and just create your new legend the exact way you would like to see it, then reimport the image into Arc.

Comment: Please specify what software you're using and add some additional tags

Answer (score 0):

How about using an 'Intersect' tool. Just create a new polygon shapefile, copy all features from your 3 shapefiles. 
[image]

and run Intersect
[image]

just to get an extra layer with all overlaps
[image]

If you have more time to play with data, you can intersect only two layers a time just to identify and symbolise intersections of each shapefile (1 and 2, 1 and 3, 2 and 3)